# Perl webcode deploy script

Tags: perl, windows-server-2008-r2, web-deployment

I am creating a Perl script to deploy webcode (Windows 2008 Server). I need to first Copy all of the old files from the destination folder and create an archive dir for the files with a timestamp trailing on the archive dir name (arc_dir.20131217). Move the files into the archive. Then I need to copy the code from the source dir into the destination folder. However it is not working at all and I am absolutely clueless as to why.

Two things, I am very green with Perl as will be shortly seen and I do not want someone to do the code for me. It kind of defeats the purpose of learning. Direction and a dialogue would be great. I am a veterans dream, willing to learn and I desire to write only clean code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use File::Copy;  #Gives you access to the "move" command
use File::Path;  #Copies data recursively from one dir and creates a new dir
use POSIX;



#Set Directories 
use constant {
    TIMESTAMP        => strftime("%Y%M%d%H%M%S", localtime);
    Source_Dir       => "C:\Users\Documents\Source_Dir",
    destination_Dir  => "C:\Users\Documents\Destination_Dir",
    ARCHIVE          => "C:\Users\Documents\arc_dir.TIMESTAMP",
};
#Creates new directory to archive old files
make_path('C:\Users\Shaun\Documents\arc_dir.TIMESTAMP');


#Need to copy destination dir, create archive dir and paste data to it
#Opens destination_Dir, so I can read from it
opendir my $dir, destination_Dir;

# Loop through directory and grab all of the files and store in var
while (my $file = readdir $dir) {
    my $destination_Dir = destination_Dir . "/" . "$file";
    move $destination_Dir, ARCHIVE;

#Loop through directory and copy all webcode to destination_Dir
opendir my $dir, Source_Dir;

while (my $file = readdir $dir) {
my $Source_Dir = Source_Dir . "/" . "$file";
move $Source_Dir, destination_Dir;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some syntax errors in the script.  I would use the -c on the command line to the PERL to check the syntax of the script (such as perl -c ).  Please make sure your () and {} are matched.

The other item is that backwards slash (\) need to be escaped with a backward slash (\) when in double quotes (").  Otherwise it is just escaping the next character in the string (and is probably not what you want for a path name). Strings in double quotes are interpolated before being processed, where single quotes are not (Nice explanation of the difference between sinqle quotes and doubles: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=401006).  You may want to change the sinqle quotes you have to double quotes in your makepath call. Otherwise TIMESTAMP will not be changed and the directory will have the name TIMESTAMP.

I would also suggest putting in some print statement to indicate what is being done and to give feedback that items are progressing.  Such as printing the "moving $destination_Dir to ARCHIVE" and "moving $Source_Dir to destination_Dir" would let you know files are being moved.